# Need to install statsmodels 0.13 but doesnt work

Tags: statsmodels

Hi im looking to use the last version of statsmodels who is currently in development(0.13) but whenever i tried do it on Spyder keeps getting the oficial version, my problem is that the function i want isnt there.

The code i tried was

```
pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels
```

" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model' " this is the error that appears whenever i use this

```
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
```

Comment: What does `python -c "import statsmodels;print(statsmodels.__version__)"` show?  You might need to `pip uninstall statsmodels -y` once or twice to make sure it isn't installed.  You should also add the `-v` flag to `pip install -v git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git` to get a more verbose log.  You will probably get better help on the statsmodels github by opening a PR.

Comment: Building wheel for statsmodels (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for statsmodels
Failed to build statsmodels
ERROR: Could not build wheels for statsmodels which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: Can you post the full build log to a gist?

Comment: With `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple statsmodels` you should be able to install version 0.13